# SharePoint Application down in Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, application-pools, eventviewer

I got a SharePoint environment consist of Web Servers, Index Server and Database Server.
The SharePoint application has been down for unknown reason, after I check on the event viewer and the result as below:

Event ID : 1013
Computer : Web Server
Description : A process serving application pool 'AppPoolName' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '4820'.

Event ID : 8645
Computer : Database Server
Description: A time out occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the query. Rerun the query

Additional 2 informations found in Web Server:

Event ID : 1117
Description : A worker process with process id of '4820' serving application pool 'AppPoolName' has requested a recycle because it reached its private bytes memory limit.

Event ID : 1077
Description : A worker process with process id of '7352' serving application pool 'AppPoolName' has requested a recycle because it reached its virtual memory limit.

I need help to understand more about the error and how can this happen, example how can the application pool being shut down. Please advice.

Thank you in advanced.

**Addition:**
I would like to know what is the tool normally use to keep track of memory leak by SharePoint.

Comment: anyone? please help

Answer (score 1):

What does your memory usage look like on the server?

You can monitor the server for memory leaks by using:

- Task Manager
- Performance Monitor
- IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool

You can read more about it here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919790

Comment: it look OK and only consume about 10% of total memory

Comment: Have you had an increased load on the server? On the webserver, go to IIS and for the application pool in question - right click on it and select Properties. Then increase the value for "Shutdown worker processes after being idle for (time in minutes)"

Comment: I tried this in my VPC to increase the idle timeout from 20 minutes to 50 minutes, it not make any much different also.

Comment: On your App Pool, how much "Maximum virtual memory" and "Maximum used memory" do you have configured?

Comment: Hi, Maximum Virtual Memory = 2000MB and Maximum Used Memory = 1900MB at Web Server for SharePoint 2007. But both Web Server the memory configuration not the same amount